# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) installation and configuration?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio Professional 2015. So, does that mean it already has SSMS pre-installed with it, or it needs to be done separately.

My need is: Report generation using SSMS, from data coming from query behind SQL Server.

So, what needs to be exactly done to configure SSMS into SQL Server with VS 2015.[image: Reference to SQL software installed.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon deep diving even more, got the answer.
Option One: Google for 'SQL Server Data Tools' installer, compatible with your VS. Run the Installer.
Option Two: Open Visual Studio 2015 - Tools > Extension and Updates. Find/Search for 'SQL Server Data Tools' update option. Run it.

I'm still not sure if there comes a complete package of Visual Studio along with Data Tools, but I don't think it does. As we still need to add certain packages into VS Installer as per need.